# On which abstraction level would you do TDD?

Tags: design, tdd

**Problem**

I find myself nailing the class structure down by having too many unit tests which makes making changes hard.

**Example**

Assume we have a class A which uses classes B1 and B2.
Class B1 uses classes C1 and C2.

[image]

I start off by writing tests first for class A. During that process, classes B1 and B2 are created. To make sure that classes B1 and B2 work, I start writing tests for B1 and B2. Same for C1 and C2.

Now, I end up having unit tests for all the different levels off abstraction. Assuming class A was for example a payroll system and classes B1, B2, C1 and C2 came to existence while building A.

**Question**

Where did I go wrong in my process? Shouldn't I have written tests for levels B and C? Should my unit tests in level A cover all the functionality in levels B and C?

What is the process which will lead to the "correct" unit tests and a flexible design?

Perhaps you can make an example with two or more levels of abstraction and show me your process and the code (including unit tests and production code and design) that comes out of your process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly just recently [Justin Searls wrote a blog post](http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2014-01-25-the-failures-of-intro-to-tdd.html) covering this topic. He identified 6 causes that might generate the pain you are experimenting using TDD and suggest a different approach to do learn TDD.

I think it can relate to what you are describing in your workflow.

Here's a summary of the 6 different failures Justin identified when applying TDD.

> - Failure #1: Encouraging Large Units
> - Failure #2: Encouraging Costly Extract Refactors
> - Failure #3: Characterization Tests of Greenfield Code
> - Failure #4: Redundant test coverage
> - Failure #5: Eliminating Redundancy Sacrifices Regression Value
> - Failure #6: Making a Mess with Mocks

In reaction to this post, [Uncle Bob destroys it all.](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html) (with an exception regarding the up front Architecture/Design).

Basically Uncle Bob reminds us of the core principles behind TDD. And this is where I think you will find your answer.

1. Code your test first. (test fails (red))
2. Code the logic (test is green)
3. Refactor to make your code readable and maintainable.

Uncle Bob says:

> ... the Author argues that the new smaller units need new unit tests. That's news to me. I certainly don't rewrite my tests just because I extracted some functions or classes.

TDD is the practice to Test First. It doesn't require one class to have its associated unit test. As long as you are testing first. Make sure the intention of  your tests are very clear and specific. It'll help you refactor properly your code (once the test are green), identifying properly the different responsibilities and interfaces you need to extract.

I also make sure my tests are readable as they might be read as a form of documentation specifying the intention behind the code. Sometimes that implies I have to refactor them and I may end up with unit tests for my different classes, or may not entirely.

Uncle Bob finishes his article with some good architecture material. He explains when to do up front design and when not to do it. Basically, you do it when you know there will be a separation of concern. Here's what he says about it:

> ... So our up front decisions can be limited to choosing a user experience, and choosing the architectural pattern that is most consistent with that user experience. Once those choices are made, we can TDD the problem domain into existence.

I hope you'll find those two blog posts useful. I certainly enjoyed reading them.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to these sources, very interesting read

Comment: I think what Uncle Bob says about not having to rewrite tests when making extractions is really important. Tests do NOT necessarily need to mirror the implementation. Does this mean that some tests will start out as "unit tests" but will be regarded as "integration tests" later when the code has been refactored? Yes. Do we care? No, because those tests are still valuable.

Comment: I do not agree with Uncle Bob. You do not refactor code just to give it readability. In a certain way, you create classes and methods to encourage reusability (one big guideline of POO). As you apply patterns to create reusable code. In a complex business solution, I don't know how you can ensure that nobody will try to reuse your code. If this reused code is not covered by tests, tests will be written afterwards. So it is not TDD.

Comment: What Uncle Bob describes is BDD, which is a little part of TDD (it emphasizes on behavior ! BDD is TDD but TDD is not BDD).

Comment: @Rénald, if someone is reusing your code, they are obviously writing/modifying code. Shouldn't that person be writing unit tests? Also, in this case the extracted functionality is still being united tested - its just that there is not a 1 to 1 mapping from test files to production files.

Comment: @Daryn : you're right, and that is a point that disturbs me sometimes... fine grained tests, or what  you describe, are possibly made without a real context that reflects the use case. I have seen many projects implementing a distributed architecture with an excellent test coverage for each API... failing when all gather together. For me, fine grained TDD can never be sufficient to ensure success. In the world of RAD and Agile, it is a real strategic advantage to quickly invest on BDD.

Comment: (After reading my first answer, I now think that classes are meant to be reused by many developpers, and that's a fallacy. I now think that the purpose of an objet is just to reflect a business capability, even if it is only a singleton...).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't go wrong.

- TDD involves Unit Testing; that is, it tests methods.  You have methods at all three levels of your project, not just level A.
- Writing tests at level A to test functionality through levels B and C isn't TDD; it's integration testing.  You're still going to want to do this, but it doesn't have anything to do with your unit tests.
- You test your individual methods at various levels of the project by decoupling them from the other layers.  This can be done by using mocks or stubs.

**Worth noting**
It is a common misconception that practicing TDD will automatically "grow" an architectural design for your program.  *It won't.*  You still have to create an architecture for your program yourself.  What TDD *will* do is force you to write code that is *testable,* which will assist you in creating a sensible and robust architecture.

Comment: I understand your point with integration testing. Am also familiar with mocks and stubs. But still: I change the structure of A and all of a sudden end up having to change B1 (including its interface and mock respectively) and throw away C2. I'm probably lacking experience in design and SOLID principles. Very good point in your "worth noting" addition.

Comment: To build on the 'worth noting' section - [Where unit testing fails](http://hmemcpy.com/2011/06/where-unit-testing-fails/)

Comment: @Lernkurve: You might be intuiting a different problem there, which deserves a different question. If you're *frequently* making a change to A that removes a need for C, you're probably not abstracting in the right places. But that has nothing to do with TDD.

Comment: -1. I strongly disagree with this answer. You should be testing behaviours, not implementation details - when you extract classes from A, the code they contain is still covered by A's tests. So you don't need new tests for them. I also disagree with your definition of 'unit' vs 'integration' tests.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson you seem to be arguing against assertions I did not make.   The tests I am talking about are unit tests of public methods, and if exercising components to see how they interoperat is not integration testing, then I don't know what is.

Comment: "Writing tests at level A to test functionality through levels B and C isn't TDD" - well, it is, but it may be not "unit testing" any more. TDD creates tests for a behaviour of A. When A is refactored into smaller units, those former unit tests may become magically "integration tests" - but does it really matter?